# NAT how to configure with a VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, nat

Good morning, I'm in trouble. I need to be able to connect to my Windows PC (not locally) and **I cannot open my router ports** (my internet provider doesn't let me). So I've been thinking on creating a VPN, I followed some tutorials but I wasn't able to connect to it.

**The only thing my ISP allows me to do is enabling NAT**, I've been reading that what it does is forward packages from internet to an IP (or something like that). So, my question is what can I do to make this possible?

Hamachi isn't a suitable solution because I'm not able to access to it from my iPad (and it also slows the internet connection considerably).

PS: my router is a cisco DPC3825 and of course the password isn't provided by my ISP if you know some way to bypass it and be able to access to the config will be sooo much easy.

Comment: TeamViewer is usually good for that, as it doesn't have to punch through a firewall from the outside, it's 'invited in' from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to setup any of the usual VPN softwares to work without a portforward somewhere, so I suggest either getting the admin password([link](http://communityforums.rogers.com/t5/forums/forumtopicpage/board-id/Getting_connected/message-id/8420#M8420)), or obeying their rules.

Maybe an email to support can forward it for you, or open it up so you can administer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third-party software to bypass the NAT-limitations.
I can recommend [TeamViewer](http://teamviewer.com). By default it uses Port 80 (HTTP-Connections) outbound connections and works perfectly with NAT-Routers.

Once installed on the target machine you can configure it to start up on Windows start and set up a permanent password. It's even possible to establish VPN-connections to the target machine and access it via RDP.